# AngularJS $watchCollection gives me wrong value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, input, collections

I'm having a problem with AngularJS $watchCollection. It's the first time I'm using this function so I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong but the values I get are not the good ones. Here's my html code (which is in a ng-repeat):

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       aria-label="..." 
       ng-disabled="!userOwnsScore(song)"
       ng-model="selDeleteSongs[song.idsong]"
       ng-true-value="'{{song.idsong}}'"
       ng-false-value="'undefined'">
```

And here's my $watchCollection function:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('selDeleteSongs', function(newVal) {
  // debugger
  console.log(newVal);
});
```

When I debug my code on firefox here's what I get as a result (selDeleteSongs list):

```
[159: 158]
```

Now the ng-model value is the good one: 159 and my value should also be 159 since I'm using 'song.idsong' for both (ng-model and ng-true-value).

To give you an idea about the situation: I have a list of songs, and this list is updated everytime I add, delete or update a song. Now once the list has been updated my view changes. So when I select a specific song I should get its true values which I do get everywhere but with the 'ng-true-value'. I don't understand how 'song.idsong' gives me 2 differents values in ng-model and ng-true-value.

Comment: Have you tried to pass 2 parameters? `$scope.$watchCollection('selDeleteSongs', function(newVal, oldVal) {`

Comment: Yes I did to debug my problem but it still gives me the wrong parameters...

Comment: Consider to make a plnkr to demonstrate your issue then.